# Is it overkill to define the closure of a set $A,A\subseteq B$ by the union of the range of the recursive function $h(0)=A, h(n^+) = h(n)\cup f[h(n)]$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f:B\to B,A\subseteq B$.

> Is it overkill to define the closure of a set $A,A\subseteq B$ over $f$ by the
>   union of the range of the recursive function $h(0)=A, h(n^+) =
>  h(n)\cup f[h(n)]$?

I saw this in an exercise in a book. But if you take $h\cap \{0,1\}\times A$ then its range would be $\{A,A\cup f[A]\}$ which has as a union the closure anyway. Seems like overcomplication to me. Is there a benefit in defining the closure recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused in thinking that the union of $\{A,A\cup f[A]\}$ is the closure. In general that is not a closure of $A$ under $f$. Think of $A=\{1\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=2x$. Then you need to iterate the $h$ function infinitely many times and take the union of all the ranges of $h$ to get the correct closure which is $2\mathbb{N}^+$.

If your confusion is why we keep unioning up sets that we already have in the result, that's a bit harder to explain. Essentially the idea is that you want the limit version of the $h(n)$ sets. Since they are all included in each other the easiest way to get the limit is to just go ahead and union them all up.